# Are character arrays the only type that have some form of null-termination?

Tags: c++, arrays

I've read some of my friend's code and seen functions like this:

```
int foo(int* arr, int n)
{
  // ... 
}
```

which he then calls like this:

```
int myArr [] = {69, 69, 69, 69, 69};
int f = foo(myArr, sizeof(myArr)/sizeof(int));
```

Now, I understand that `sizeof(myArr)/sizeof(int)` is dividing the size of `myArr` in bytes by the size of an `int` in bytes, thus returning the length of `myArray`. However, I don't understand how `sizeof(myArr)` is implemented unless there's some sort of generic null element that terminates arrays and then `sizeof(...)` works similar to how `strlen(...)` works:

```
 size_t strlen(char* c)
 {
     size_t k = 0;
     while (*c != '\0')
     {
         ++k;
         ++c;
      }
     return k;
 }
```

Now, if `sizeof(...)` does work similar to that, then I don't see why, when passing an array to a function, you can't simply do

```
int foo(int* arr)
{
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    // ....
}
```

which is simpler way of writing functions because the array is essentially being passed in as a single unit that gets unpacked.

My guess is that arrays of non-character type don't have the null-termination property that character arrays do. In that case, how does `sizeof(...)` work? And what is the point of null-termination in character arrays anyhow? Why are they created differently than any other array?

Anyways, I was wondering whether someone could clear up all the obvious confusion that I have.

Comment: Character arrays are not implicitly null terminated, string literals are though. `sizeof` is a compile time construct that evaluates to a constant value representing the size of the object as the compiler sees it. It does not runtime or compile time checks for null termination.

Comment: In C++, `std::vector` or other container classes should be preferred over raw arrays. Then you don't need to pass size information around

Comment: The size of an array is encoded in the type. `sizeof` returns the size of the type.

Comment: Note that the use of `sizeof()` in your `int foo(int* arr)` function will give you just the size of the `int*` pointer, but never the size of the array it points to!

Comment: By the way, there's not really a rule that character arrays must be null terminated. For example `{'h','e','l','l','o'}` is a perfectly fine character array.

Comment: @chrashmstr has a point, why don't you tag this question `c` instead of c++. The particular topic is not related to any c++ feature

Comment: In C, all of this pointer/array stuff is daily business. In C++, it works but is not idiomatic (i.e. not natural, not usual, typically replaced by something else). The first thing a C++ programmer worth his or her money would ask when seeing a function like your `foo` would be "Why in the world don't they pass a vector?"

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` works on arrays because the compiler knows the length at compile time. If you pass that array to a function, it turns into a pointer, at which point the compiler doesn't know the full size of the array anymore.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

void printPointerSize(int* a) {
    // a is a pointer, and all pointers are 8 bytes (64 bits) on my machine
    std::cout << "int* pointer argument has size: " << sizeof a << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // the compiler determines from the initializer that this is an int[5]
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    // since the compiler knows that a is an int[5],
    // then sizeof a is 5 * sizeof int
    std::cout << "int[5] has size: " << sizeof a << std::endl;
    printPointerSize(a);
}
```

Output (on a platform with 64-bit pointers and 32-bit integers):

```
int[5] has size: 20
int* pointer argument has size: 8
```

---

Note that if you try to create a function that takes an array as an argument, the compiler will just turn it into a pointer anyway:

```
void printPointerSize(int a[5]) {
    // this will print the size of a pointer,
    // not the size of a 5-element int array
    std::cout << "int[5] argument has size: " << sizeof a << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It's possible to pass an array while also passing its size, but it requires the method to be templated. The syntax looks like: template <int N> void foo(const char (&s)[N] { cout << "S is: " << s " and N is :" << N; }

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Brandon's answer, you need to distinguish between *array capacity* and *array size*.

**Array Capacity**
Array Capacity is the maximum number items the array can hold.  There can be from 0 to capacity number of items in the array.  Which brings up the question, "how many items are in the array?"

**Array Size**
Array Size is the number of valid items in the array.  An array that has a capacity of 20 items, may only have 3 valid items in it.
Example:

```
char array[20];
array[0] = 'M';
array[1] = 'e';
array[2] = 'a';
array[3] = 't';
```

The above array has a capacity of 20, but only 4 valid items.
Repeating the question, *"How many items are in the array?"*

The C++ language does not maintain the number of items in an array.  The `sizeof` operator returns the capacity of an array, but not the size.

**The size of an array must be maintained in a separate variable.**  Some crafty programmers can use an array slot to maintain this value.  So when passing an array, you will have to pass:  the array (or pointer to it), the capacity and the size.  Most starting programmers forget about the size parameter, which leads to many difficult defects that are hard to find.